# C++ Cannot Install Font in Windows 10

Tags: c++, windows, fonts, truetype

I have two fonts which are used by my Windows C++ app (Ubuntu, Roboto Regular and Roboto Thin) and I have tried to install them with AddFontResource and AddFontResourceEx but it does not work in the latest Anniversary Edition of Windows 10 and also in Windows Server 2008 and 2012.
The font does not get installed. So I have created my Font Installation C++ class.
In my C++ / VSNET2015 function I do the following:

1. Copy the .TTF font files in C:\Windows\Fonts
2. Add the .TTF font files to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts  FontName (TrueType) - FontFile.ttf
3. Call AddFontResource(FontFileName)
4. Send WM_FONTCHANGE message.

The fonts get installed and works every time, but is working until  I restart Windows then it doesn't. The font files are there and the registry entries are ok also the fonts show in the Windows Fonts Explorer, but it cannot be used in my application and the fonts cannot be deleted from Windows Fonts Explorer because the fonts are in use (with the app closed).

```
 /**********************************************************************/
BOOL CInstallFont::InstallFont(CString strFontName, CString strFontFileName, BOOL bRegular)
{
    m_strFontName = strFontName;
    m_strFontFileName = strFontFileName;

    if (IsFontInstalled() == TRUE)
        if (CanCreateFont(strFontName)) // try to create the font and if successful, then don't install it again
            return TRUE;

    /*****************************************************/
    /* Copy Font to Windows\Fonts folder                 */
    /*****************************************************/
    CPathW pwSrc;
    CPathW pwDest;
    CString strTmp, strTmp2;

    FolderUtils f;

    CString strFontsFolder = _T("");

    f.GetSpecialFolder(CSIDL_FONTS, strFontsFolder);

    strTmp2 = theApp.m_strAppFolder;
    pwSrc.Combine(strTmp2, strFontFileName);    
    pwDest.Combine(strFontsFolder, strFontFileName);

    BOOL bRet=CopyFile(pwSrc, pwDest, TRUE);

    if (bRet == FALSE)
    {
        strTmp = _T("Error: Cannot copy font file ");
        strTmp += strFontFileName;
        AfxMessageBox(strTmp, MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
    }
    /*****************************************************/
    /* Add Font to Registry                              */
    /*****************************************************/
    CRegKey reg;
    LONG lRet=0;

    lRet = reg.Open(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, _T("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\Fonts"), KEY_READ | KEY_WRITE);
    if (lRet == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        CString strFullFontName = strFontName;

        strFullFontName += _T(" (TrueType)");
        reg.SetStringValue(strFullFontName, strFontFileName); // For OpenType fonts you need to change the value here
    }
    reg.Close();

    /*****************************************************/
    //AddFontResource(strFontFileName);
    SendMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_FONTCHANGE, 0, 0);

    return TRUE;
}

/**********************************************************************/
int CALLBACK CInstallFont::EnumFontFamExProc(ENUMLOGFONTEX* /*lpelfe*/, NEWTEXTMETRICEX* /*lpntme*/, int /*FontType*/, LPARAM lParam)
{
    LPARAM* l = (LPARAM*)lParam;
    *l = TRUE;
    return TRUE;
}

/**********************************************************************/
/* Test to see if the font can be created                             */
BOOL CInstallFont::CanCreateFont(CString strFontName)
{
    CFont font;

    BOOL bRet=font.CreateFont(
        16,                        // nHeight
        0,                         // nWidth
        0,                         // nEscapement
        0,                         // nOrientation
        FW_NORMAL,                   // nWeight
        FALSE,                     // bItalic
        FALSE,                     // bUnderline
        0,                         // cStrikeOut
        DEFAULT_CHARSET,           // nCharSet
        OUT_DEFAULT_PRECIS,        // nOutPrecision
        CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS,       // nClipPrecision
        ANTIALIASED_QUALITY,       // nQuality
        DEFAULT_PITCH | FF_SWISS,  // nPitchAndFamily
        strFontName);          // lpszFacename

    font.DeleteObject();

    return bRet;
}

/**********************************************************************/
BOOL CInstallFont::IsFontInstalled()
{
    // Get the screen DC
    CDC dc;
    if (!dc.CreateCompatibleDC(NULL))
    {
        return false;
    }
    LOGFONT lf = { 0 };
    // Any character set will do
    lf.lfCharSet = DEFAULT_CHARSET;

    // Set the facename to check for
    wcscpy_s(lf.lfFaceName, m_strFontName.GetLength()*2, (LPCTSTR)m_strFontName);

    LPARAM lParam = 0;
    // Enumerate fonts
    ::EnumFontFamiliesEx(dc.GetSafeHdc(), &lf, (FONTENUMPROC)EnumFontFamExProc, (LPARAM)&lParam, 0);
    return lParam ? TRUE : FALSE;
}
```

I call the function with the following parameters

```
CInstallFont instFont;

instFont.InstallFont(_T("Roboto Light"), _T("Roboto-Light.ttf"));
instFont.InstallFont(_T("Roboto Thin"), _T("Roboto-Thin.ttf"));
instFont.InstallFont(_T("Roboto Regular"), _T("Roboto-Regular.ttf"));
```

Comment: While it may be obvious to you, it isn't to me: What's your question?

Comment: I have added a question

Comment: I guess the more important question to ask first would be: *"Is there anything wrong with my code? I have verified that all calls succeed."*, accompanied by a [mcve]. You just jumped to the conclusion, that your code cannot possibly be wrong, and there must be some protection built into the system.

Comment: Ok, I have added the font install code.

Comment: Protip: don't install fonts on users' machines without their permission. Especially not when you don't even check to see if they already have those fonts installed and your version is going to be older. Bundle your fonts and load the assets from your APPDATA dir, unless the user has given you permission to install fonts onto the system.

Comment: _don't install fonts on users' machines without their permission_ ... I second that. It sounds like the fonts are only used in the GUI of your application, so you should privately load them from the application folder using `AddFontResourceEx( filePath, FR_PRIVATE, nullptr )` at every startup of your application. The FR_PRIVATE flag will hide the fonts from all other applications.

Comment: I have tried addfontresource but it does not work on Windows 10 Anniversary Edition and Windows Server. If you look closely at my function it already checks to see if the font is installed. I will try again with AddFontResourceEx with FR_PRIVATE.

Comment: I have tried AddFontResourceEx on Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard and the font cannot be used by the application

Comment: It seems that AddFontResource works only for Fonts used by GDI and not by GDI+ and I use the fonts with GDI+

Comment: When I install the font manually with Windows Font Explorer everything works perfectly.

Comment: For GDI+ there is class [PrivateFontCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms534491(v=vs.85).aspx) which solves a similar purpose as AddFontResourceEx with FR_PRIVATE. If you like I can post a full answer showing how to use it.

Comment: I have tried that, see this question...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42595856/fonts-added-with-addfontresourceex-are-not-working-in-gdi/42597015#42597015